# I need a Proxy server with remote ip permission management

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

I need a proxy server so i can remotely manage the ip addresses who can use proxy server.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Are you asking for advice on which proxy solution to use? What internal resources are you managing with this proxy, intranet web servers? Database servers?

Comment: Yes I'm asking for a solution if there is one. I need a Web Proxy Server with allow access ip management. In proxy servers your users are ip addresses. when you connect to the proxy server, proxy server sees you as an ip address address he he can let you request from server or not! I want to be able to manage ( add and remote ) these ip permission, for example i want to tell server to add a permission for 127.0.0.1 and later I deny 127.0.0.1 from accessing the proxy server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squid can do this.  For remote management, just use SSH.

Comment: I searched the internet for command lines in order to manage http accesses but I couldn't find any thing... Can you describe how to do this with squid?

Comment: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/